# How to add email verification in a parse server

Tags: android, heroku, parse-platform, mlab

I recently migrated my database from my Parse account to MongoLab and I've also set up a Parse Server on Heroku. Everything is working great except that I want to add an email verification feature using the emailVerified parameter that exists in Parse and I don't see how to do it because I didn't had the option activated before migrating my database.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you succeed with this? I have same problem. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have to add the feature yourself using a combination of Cloud Code and a mailing service such as Mandril or SendGrid.

Cannot currently find the reference, but believe I saw somewhere that this is the case. 
It would make sense as any mailing service would need some form of credentials in order to handle emailing.

You could of course also have a look at the source code to verify: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

Comment: I've look at at the link but I just can't find what I'm searching, I think that I just need the lines that allow the email verification in the parse server. Anyway I'm will try to use SendGrid to achieve that, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SendGrid for this. You need to install parse-server-sendgrid-adapter to your parse-server directory.

Run this command inside your parse-server directory:

```
npm i parse-server-sendgrid-adapter
```

After installation finishes. You need to set variables inside your index.js file.

```
var SimpleSendGridAdapter = require('parse-server-sendgrid-adapter');
```

And add these to your var api = new ParseServer function as parameters:

```
      .
      .
      .
      appName: '', //enter your app name
      publicServerURL: '', //enter your server url
      verifyUserEmails: true,
      emailAdapter: new SimpleSendGridAdapter({
      apiKey: '***', //enter your api key
      fromAddress: '' //the address that mails will be sending.
    }),
    customPages: {
      invalidLink: 'http://yourpage/link_invalid.html',
      verifyEmailSuccess: 'http://yourpage/verify_email_success.html',
      choosePassword: 'http://yourpage/new_password.html',
      passwordResetSuccess: 'http://yourpage/sucess.html'
    },
    .
    .
    .
```

Also enable email verification from your app's Parse dashboard.